How to mock React.UseContext with Jest
I am trying to write a unit test for a component that contains the usage of values that come from a context file.
 import { globalContext } from "../../globalContext";
  const { rowId, num, activeNum } = useContext(globalContext);

In my unit test how can I mock this hook so that I can set these values to whatever I need them to be?

In your text, you don't mock the hook but wrap the component you are testing with the corresponding context provider with the values you want to pass in --
so something like
<YourContext.Provider value={{rowId, num, active num}}>
        <ComponentYouAreTesting/>
</YourContext.Provider>

